# Modal doesn't write the link of a PDF file generated with TCPDF, after an AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, tcpdf

This code works. So far, I've only found one exception that breaks it, and it happens only on the live server, on localhost it still works fine all the time.

So, what's the problem.

Basically I generate a PDF file with TCPDF (note that the file is pretty big, over 700 pages) using AJAX and the call returns the link to the file, which I will then append to a modal to let the user choose whether he wants to go to the file, or download it.

This is the AJAX code.

```
$('#stampa-file').on('submit', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'stampa_file.php?act=stampa',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $('#stampa-file').serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {                   
            if($.trim(data) == 'query_error')
            {
                alert('Qualcosa è andato storto. Riprova.');
            }
            else if($.trim(data) == 'stampa_error')
            {
                alert('Seleziona almeno una sezione');
            }
            else
            {                   
                $('#stampa-file')[0].reset();
                $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
                $('#document-link').empty();
                $('#document-link-download').empty();
                $('#document-link').append('<a href="files/<?php echo $_COOKIE['NomeDB'];?>/'+ data +'" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" target="_blank" style="width: 120px;"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Visualizza PDF</a>');
                $('#document-link-download').append('<a href="files/<?php echo $_COOKIE['NomeDB'];?>/'+ data +'" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" target="_blank" style="width: 120px;" download><i class="fas fa-download"></i> Scarica PDF</a>');
                $('#viewFile').modal('show');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is the TCPDF code.

```
    //I generate the PDF above this comment. Below only the link generation, PDF output and save the file into the database.
//Close and output PDF document
$replace = array(" ", "'");
$replacer = array("");
$nome = strtolower($query_ente['nome']);
$now = date("Y_m_d_H_i_s", time());         
$link = trim(str_replace($replace, $replacer, 'RDAT_'.$nome.'_'.$now.'.pdf'));
ob_clean();
$pdf -> Output($path_stampa_file.$link,'F'); 

$output = '';
$timestamp = time();
$result_inserimento = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO files (link, nome, timestamp, categoria) VALUES ('$link', '$link', '$timestamp', 'stampa_rdt')");
if($result_inserimento)
{
    /*Registro Attività*/
    include 'connessione_multi.php';
    session_start();
    $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
    $result_user_info = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sessioni_login WHERE session_id='$user_check'");
    $query_user_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_user_info);
    $session_user_id = $query_user_info['id_utente'];
    $id_utente = $session_user_id;
    $descrizione = 'ha eseguito la stampa del file: '.$link.'';
    $timestamp = time();
    $indirizzo_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $result_attivita = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO attivita (id_utente, descrizione, timestamp, indirizzo_ip) VALUES ('$id_utente', '$descrizione', '$timestamp', '$indirizzo_ip')");

    $output = $link;
}
else
{
    $output = 'query_error';
}   
echo $output;
```

Like I said I have everything working fine, but I can't understand why in just one case, for one customer and only on the live server, not on localhost, it fails. Basically when it fails, what I get in the result of the AJAX call is an empty value and the link in the modal looks like this

`www.mysite.com/files/customer_name/`

instead of

`www.mysite.com/files/customer_name/RDAT_customername_timestamp.pdf`

I tried some stuff, but I still can't find a solution.

Things that I tried:

- get the link from the database by calling another AJAX request inside the success of the first AJAX call, printed the link in a hidden DIV inside the page and get the link with jQuery .text() and then append it to the modal;
- append the link in the "complete" event of the AJAX call instead of "success";
- get the link from the database right after it gets saved on the TCPDF generation file, rather than using the same variable $link in the same file;
- removed every action in the success event of the AJAX call and only leave the append events;

All of these tests work fine all the time, except for that one time that it fails on the live server.

I really have no other option at this point.

Comment: Probably due to timeout, did check execution time?

Comment: Yes, execution time is set to 600, I also use a `set_time_limit(3600);` inside the TCPDF generation file. Also, I forgot to mention that the file is generated successfully, it is on the database and it's inside the files folder. If I go to the link manually, the file opens normally and there's everthing inside. @Janis

Comment: What is `$_COOKIE['NomeDB']; ` ? I can not see the variable in your code

Comment: @KubiRoazhon it's a folder name that I have stored in a Cookie, don't worry about it